# How to apply more than one filter to the image using Aforge

Tags: c#, filter, aforge, colorfilter

I can filter red and blue color separately but i want to filter both at the same time.. so my code is like this

```
//FOR RED COLOR
ColorFiltering filter = new ColorFiltering();
filter.Red = new IntRange(100, 255);
filter.Green = new IntRange(0, 75);
filter.Blue = new IntRange(0, 75);
filter.ApplyInPlace(image1);
MyDraw(image1);


// FOR BLUE COLOR
EuclideanColorFiltering filter2 = new EuclideanColorFiltering();
filter2.CenterColor = new RGB(Color.FromArgb(9, 39, 101));
filter2.Radius = 50;
filter2.ApplyInPlace(image1);

MyDraw(image1);


public void MyDraw(Bitmap image)
{
BlobCounter blobCounter = new BlobCounter();
blobCounter.MinWidth = 2;
blobCounter.MinHeight = 2;
blobCounter.FilterBlobs = true;
blobCounter.ObjectsOrder = ObjectsOrder.Size;

Grayscale grayFilter = new Grayscale(0.2125, 0.7154, 0.0721);
Bitmap grayImage = grayFilter.Apply(image);

blobCounter.ProcessImage(grayImage);
Rectangle[] rects = blobCounter.GetObjectsRectangles();
foreach (Rectangle recs in rects)
{

    if (rects.Length > 0)
    {
        Rectangle objectRect = rects[0];
        //Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(image);
        Graphics g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
        reception = "Cam," + objectRect.X + "," + objectRect.Y;
        Console.WriteLine("X: " + objectRect.X + "   Y:" + objectRect.Y.ToString());

        using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(252, 3, 26), 2))
        {

            g.DrawRectangle(pen, objectRect);
        }
        int objectX = objectRect.X + (objectRect.Width / 2);
        int objectY = objectRect.Y + (objectRect.Height / 2);
        g.DrawString(objectX.ToString() + "X" + objectY.ToString(), new Font("Arial", 12), Brushes.Red, new System.Drawing.Point(250, 1));
        g.Dispose();
    }
}
}
```

So i want to recognize blue and red shapes on webcam and draw a rectangle around recognized shape. For now, I can do it as red or blue. But I want to recognize red and blue colors at the same time

how can i add multiple filters?

Comment: Not sure if this is exactly what you want, but you can add two or more filters into a sequence. They will be performed *in sequence*, but you only call `Apply` once. Read about this filter [here](http://www.aforgenet.com/aforge/framework/docs/html/1bd9732e-de3f-8ac9-1c45-e9c2b526f81d.htm).

Comment: @AndersGustafsson, thank you Anders, i think its what I am looking for